# What is the sum of the probability of two events occurring?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this sum:

$$\sum_{k,j = n, k\neq j}^{N} P(A_{k})P(A_j)$$

I am told that what is given above is equal to $$\left(\sum_{k=n}^{N} P(A_k)\right)^{2} - \sum_{k=n}^{N}\left(P(A_k)\right)^{2}$$

what information do i need in order to see why this equality holds?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $\left(\sum_{k = n}^NP(A_k)\right)^2$?

Comment: no i don't know how to do that

Comment: Bermudes comment gives the answer. This has nothing to do with probability. I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: Try to generalize the formula $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You only need
$$(x_n + \cdots+ x_N)^2 = x_n^2+ \cdots + x_N^2 + \sum_{\stackrel{k,l=n}{k \neq l}}^Nx_kx_l $$

Comment: Although this is true, it is not an answer, you only rewrote the question. The OP asks *why* this holds.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier : I did it on purpose as students are often confused when seemingly "more complex symbols"  occur within easily to be verified algebraic formulas.

Comment: I didn't say that your comment was not appropriate. But it is appropriate to put comments in the comment section.

Comment: I would leave it to the OP to accept or not to accept it as an answer. When looking across the pages here on MSE there is plenty of very short "hinting" answers.

Comment: thank you, @trancelocation. i was able to understand immediately from your answer (although i feel kind of silly now).

Comment: @user477465  You are welcome. Don't feel silly. This just happens. Just rewriting with easier symbols often helps to clarify a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is the result of "mulyiplying out" the expression
$$(x_n+\cdots+ x_N)^2$$
Write this as
$$(x_n+\cdots+x_N)\cdot (x_n+\cdots + x_N)$$
and proceed as you would have proceeded if you had only two summands between each pair of brackets: what is the contribution of $x_n$ from the left side to the result? it is 
$$x_n(x_n+\cdots + x_N)=x_n^2+x_nx_{n+1}+\cdots + x_nx_N=x_n^2+\sum_{j\neq n}x_nx_j$$
more generally, given $n\leq i\leq N$, the contribution of $x_i$ from the left side to the result is
$$x_i(x_n+\cdots + x_N)=x_i^2+\sum_{j\neq i}x_ix_j$$
Therefore, the total result is
$$x_1^2+\cdots + x_n^2 + \sum_{i=n}^N\left(\sum_{j\neq i}x_jx_i\right)$$
now put $x_k=P(A_k)$ and you are done.